# Getters on spritekit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skscene, sknode

I have a little problem. Let me introduce it to you:
On SpriteKit, we have MyScene.m and .h file. This class have a property called "size". We can access it from the MyScene.m file by using "self.size".
I've created a class called Menu, so we have a .m and a .h. This class is a subclass of "SKNode".
My problem is that I want to get the value of "size" property of MyScene class in my Menu class.
Because I have some nodes which I will add to Menu object, and their position will depend on MyScene "size" property.

Can you please tell me how to do it.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `initWithSceneSize:(CGSize)size` method for your Menu class and then store the size in a ivar or property of your Menu class.

Example with a ivar in your .m :

```
@implementation MenuClass
{
    CGSize sceneSize;
}

-(instancetype)initWithSceneSize:(CGSize)size
{
     sceneSize = size;
     if (self = [super init])
     {
         // do whatever
     }
     return self;
}
```

Now you can use the `sceneSize` ivar wherever you want in that class for sizing and/or alignment of elements.

Another option is detailed in the other answer , which is using the scene property of `SKNode`.

That is a viable option but be aware that if the node is not currently a child of the node tree, the `scene` property will be `nil`. So you should make sure that it is currently added to the scene's node tree.

An example would be that if you tried to use the `scene` property in your constructor, it would not be accessible at that point and you'll be baffled.

Definitely a viable option and a good one, but just be aware of that aspect or that might be your next question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scene` property of `SKNode` to retrieve the scene that contains the node. For more info see [SKNode Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/scene).